# How to get Dev C++ to find Python.h

Tags: python, c++, ide

I'm using Dev C++. Include Python.h doesnt work, and IDE states it cant find the file or directory. I can pull up the Python.h C file, so I know I have it. How do I connect two-and-two? I imagine I have to tell my IDE where the file path is, but how would I do that?

Comment: check that in dev-C++ tools > compiler options > directories > c includes and c++ includes have the path to where your Python.h is.

Comment: I am going to put is as answer please mark it as a valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that in dev-C++ tools > compiler options > directories > c includes and c++ includes have the path to where your Python.h is.